# Hot to HotSwap code in Intellij in a Spring-Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, hotswap

I'm using `spring-boot-starter` for a larger server project that opens a static socket for communication. For not always having to restart the server in `Intellij IDEA` after every code change (and thereby quit the socket connection), I'm trying to **HotSwap** the changed *.java code.

I tried as follows without success:

- added the maven `spring-boot-devtools` dependency
- Settings > `Build project automatically [yes]`
- Registry: `complier.automake.allow.when.app.running [true]`
- Run Configuration > Update Policies: `Update classes and resources`

BUT: whenever I modify a class, my application restarts automatically. Of course this will also reload the classes, but then I could also trigger the restart myself at will. I'm not gaining anything by automated restarts.

So I disabled the restarts via `spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false`. But then the code swap does not work until the server is restarted.

But is it possible at all without explicit restarts?

Sidenote: I'm not about hotswap a web-UI in the browser. I just want to have the java code reloaded.

Comment: Do you use Gradle task to run application? If you want to use IDE hotswap you should use IDE Run/Debug Configuration for launching the app.

Comment: Hot swap will not work if you change any structural part of your application. If you change a type of a parameter, the name of a method, the type it returns, you create a new method/class/etc... you will not be able to do it. In case you change something inside a method, only the class where it is will recompile and you will not need to restart the app, so I guess it would work as you want to. But for any "big" change it does not works

Comment: IDEA 2021.2 :  `Settings ->Advanced Settings -> Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running`

Answer (score 3):

That's how Spring Boot dev tools work, every change requires a restart but the restart with dev tools is much faster because it uses custom class loader:

> The restart technology provided by Spring Boot works by using two
>   classloaders. Classes that do not change (for example, those from
>   third-party jars) are loaded into a base classloader. Classes that you
>   are actively developing are loaded into a restart classloader. When
>   the application is restarted, the restart classloader is thrown away
>   and a new one is created. This approach means that application
>   restarts are typically much faster than “cold starts”, since the base
>   classloader is already available and populated.

If you want to hotswap code without restarting then one option is to use [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). Spring Boot documentation states the same:

> If you find that restarts are not quick enough for your applications
>   or you encounter classloading issues, you could consider reloading
>   technologies such as JRebel from ZeroTurnaround.

Comment: Ok so I misunderstood the feature. As JRebel does not offer a community edition, I'm probably out of luck here...

Comment: But what's options build->On Update action->Hot swap classes and update trigger if failed in last IDEa?